# Homestead v6.1.0 doesn't apply set PHP5.6

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

## Scenario

- I've updated Vagrant to 1.9
- I only have box 3.0.0
- I've cloned the master branch of Homestead and checked out tag v6.1.0

In **Homestead.yaml**, I've this site:

```
- map: m2azr.local
  to: /Code/m2azr.local
  php: "5.6"
```

When I'm doing `bash init.sh`, `vagrant up --provision` and `vagrant ssh`, I see there are **3 php versions** installed: 5.6, 7.0 and 7.1. So it seems I've the right Homestead version (described in https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead).

## Problem

The set php version in Homestead.yaml is **not** applied for site `m2azr.local`:

- `phpinfo()` shows php version `7.1.x`
- `composer install` shows an error `This package requires php ^5.6 but your PHP version (7.1.7) does not satisfy that requirement.`

Why is PHP5.6 not set?

Comment: As the referred page reads, the CLI command to use specific php version should be `php5.6 composer install`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I know that's possible. But for the site is PHP5.6 required, so it fails when I'm running my application. That's why (I guess) you can specify the php version in Homestead.yaml.

Comment: Yep, that's right, and I see no obvious reason why it does not. https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/v6.1.0/scripts/homestead.rb#L205 falls back to 7.1, so it might be wrong indent in the yaml. Could you confirm which php version is configured in `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/` line in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/m2azr.local` ?

Comment: Thanks you. But now, I get "command not found" (excuse me, no experience)

Comment: Which command?....

Comment: fastcgi_pass ... Thanks for your quick replying!

Comment: It is not a command, it is beginning of the line in the /etc/nginx/sites-available/m2azr.local file in your homestead vm. The file was generated by vagrant and I asked to confirm which version of php is used in this line. Sorry if my comment was not quite clear.

Comment: Ok, it's clear now. I see this line: `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;` (sock file exists).

Comment: But I stil have the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Alex for your help. Below, my solution.

This problem was caused by another running vagrant box with the same ip.

I changed my `ip` in `Homestead.yaml` to 192.168.20.20 (and added `subnetmask` 255.255.255.0 to the `config.vm.network` in `Homestead.rb`). Reload with provision.